# Installing Windows 8.1/10 in legacy mode on Samsung 950 Pro

Tags: ssd, bios, windows-installation

Has anyone successfully installed Windows 8.1/10 in **legacy mode** on a Samsung 950 Pro NVME SSD?

There is absolutely NOTHING on the internet on installing Windows in legacy mode to an NVME SSD.

I don't want to recommend that my friend buy one if I won't be able to set it up the way he needs it.

- Are there any issues I should be aware of?
- Are there any hacky tweaks that need to be made?
- Will there be any drop in I/O performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes;  I have many times;  Windows 10 fully supports both MBR partitions and GPT partitions

Comment: @Ramhound - Why would you downvote? The whole point of this was because there is absolutely NOTHING on the internet on installing Windows in legacy mode to an NVME SSD.

Comment: Voting is anonymous for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I disabled UEFI boot in the BIOS, booted from the USB, and crossed my fingers.

And it worked just fine :)

So the answer is Windows 10 can be installed just fine in legacy mode to a Samsung 950 Pro.